# asp.net convert C# string to javascript code

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a C# string:

```
@{
 var data = "dataTable.addRow(['Text', 1, 2])";
}
```

Now I want to put this string somewhere in javascript code (in  seciton) by using:

```
@data
```

And the result is:

```
dataTable.addRow([&#x27;Text&#x27;, 1, 2]);
```

So I tried to use:

```
@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(data);
```

And I got:

```
dataTable.addRow([\u0027Text\u0027, 1, 2]);
```

How can I get the result like:

```
dataTable.addRow(['Text', 1, 2]);
```

Comment: Try just `@HTML.Raw(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
@Html.Raw(data)
```

But I would still suggest you put js code inside .js file and do ajax to the server to retrieve the data. Some browsers might block inline javascript code in high security mode.

Comment: "Some browsers might block inline javascript code in high security mode" -- not to mention, you marry your front-end views to the razor templating engine. If you decide to use a different templating engine, or none at all, there is a lot of code to rewrite. If you grab the data from an ajax call, it can come from anywhere, as long as the data stays formatted the same. Keeps your options open for the future

Comment: That helps. It's only for my small project as I'm studying ASP.NET core. Later I want to study some front end framework (probably Angular). Thank you for your advices